# Can you suggest me the right syntax for this?

Tags: html, css

What I am trying is, when the mouse is over the link of `#first-block1`, the link of `#first-block2` should get underline. Only through CSS not javascript.

```css
#first-block1:hover {
  #first-block2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a id="first-block1" href=""><span style="color:black;">yoast.com</span> <span style="color:#515A5A">> SEO blog > SEO Basics</span></a><br><a id="first-block2" href="">Elements of Google Search Engine Results Page. SEO for ...</a></p>
```

Comment: can you add the HTML ?

Comment: The only thing you are going to get are guesses until you post the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `~` sibling selector instead of the more direct `+` next element selector since you have a `<br>` tag between your `<a>` tags. (More on selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Also, you can't nest classes/ids, unless you are using a preprocessor like SASS/SCSS/LESS.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#first-block1:hover ~ #first-block2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p><a id="first-block1" href=""><span style="color:black;">yoast.com</span> <span style="color:#515A5A">> SEO blog > SEO Basics</span></a><br><a id="first-block2" href="">Elements of Google Search Engine Results Page. SEO for ...</a></p>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! this worked!!! and also got know about selectors.

Comment: @fzn619 glad you got it figured out! You should go give an upvote to the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML, it could be

```
#first-block1:hover + #first-block2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put it on the same line.

```
 #first-block1:hover #first-block2 {
                text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#first-block1 > #first-block2:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here what I has to do if I was in charge of it:

```html
<p><a id="first-block1" href=""><span style="color:black;">yoast.com</span> <span style="color:#515A5A">> SEO blog > SEO Basics</span></a><br><a class="first-block2" style="text-decoration: none;" href="">Elements of Google Search Engine Results Page. SEO for ...</a></p>
```

```css
#first-block1:hover ~ a { 
    text-decoration: underline !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Comment: You just copied the CSS from the question and pasted it into an answer...

Comment: I copied the wrong answer, but now it's working fine, thanks!